# Calculating Running Total with a Validation Loop in python

Tags: python, validation

I am new to python and trying to calculate a running total while validating the user input. If the user inputs invalid data I am showing an error and asking the user to input the correct data. My issue is I am unable to determine how to calculate only the valid data input from the user instead of all values.

```
# This program calculates the sum of a series
# of numbers entered by the user.

#Initialize an accumulator variable.
total = 0

#Request max value from user.
max_value = int(input("Enter a value for the maximum number: "))

#Request user to enter value between 1 and max value.
number = int(input("Enter a number between 1 and " + str(max_value) + " or negative number to end: "))

#Calculate total of user input values.
while number > 0:
      total = total + number
      number = int(input("Enter a number between 1 and " + str(max_value) + " or negative number to end:"))

#Display error if user entered invalid value.
    if number == 0 or number > max_value:
        print("Number entered is invalid!")

#Print sum of valid user input data. 
else:
    print("Sum of all valid numbers you entered:", total)
```

Comment: First off, you never want to assume the user will give you the right data type like you do with `max_value` and `number`. You should wrap user input values in try/expect so that if you try casting say int("hello"), you can catch this and ask the user to try again for example.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you have added too much unnecessary code and this is a very bad practice in python. I believe that this is the answer you are looking for:
f"" = is called a formatted string and
the while loop is unnecessary
so after that, you should import sys and use the exit function under a while loop and exit under a for loop

```
from sys import exit as exit1


while True:
    max_value = int(input("Enter a value for the maximum number: "))
    if max_value<0:
        break
    number = int(input(f"Enter a number between 1 and {max_value} or negative number to end: "))
    total = max_value + number

    if number == 0 or number > max_value:
        print("Number entered is invalid!")
    else:
        print("Sum of all valid numbers you entered:", total)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response but this doesn't allow the user to enter as many number as they would like before terminating the loop. The revision above is only allowing the user to enter the max value and then one number. I am needing to allow the user to enter as many numbers as they would like until they terminate the loop with a negative number.

Comment: I have edited my answer. tell me if this is what you wanted.

Comment: The revised code is still only allowing the user to enter the max value and one number before it calculates the running total. I am needing the loop to continue until the user terminates the loop by entering a negative number. My sample code I supplied did everything except it was calculating the invalid entries in the total. I only want to the valid entries to be calculated. Hope that makes since and I appreciate your willingness to assist.

Answer (score 0):

So after reevaluating the code I wrote the first time I came up with the below and it functions as I would like. For a beginner that has only learned three chapters I think it is good. Current knowledge base is Input, Processing, Output, Decision Structures, Boolean Logic, and Repetition Structures.

```
 # This program calculates the sum of a series
 # of numbers entered by the user.

 #Initialize an accumulator variable.
 total = 0

 # Request max value from user.
 max_value = int(input("Enter a value for the maximum number: "))

 #Request number between 1 and max value.
 number = int(input("Enter a number between 1 and " + str(max_value) + " or negative 
 number to end: "))

 #Validate the user input is between 1 and max value
 # if so accumulate the number.
 while number >= 0:
     if number > 0 and number <= max_value:
        total = total + number

     elif number == 0 or number > max_value:
         print("Number entered is invalid!")

     number = int(input("Enter a number between 1 and " + str(max_value) + " or negative number to end: "))

 #Once user select a negative number, print total.
 else:
     print("Sum of all valid numbers you entered:", total)
```